# Хочу фоновой картинке добавить полупрозрачности

Tags: html, css, css3, opacity

Есть блок с фоном на который я хочу наложить эффект полупрозрачности без правки html, но не выходит.. набросал [фидл](http://jsfiddle.net/2b7dD/237/)

```css
.profile-pic {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) url("http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-pic"></div>
```

Comment: `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)` указанная здесь полупрозрачность относиться к цвету

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Два варианта:

1) Наложить `opacity` на сам блок, но видимо он вам почему-то не подходит

```
.profile-pic {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: url("http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg");
    opcity:0.5;
}
```

2) Положить фон в псевдоэлемент

```css
.profile-pic {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.profile-pic:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: url("http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/l-Wittle-puppy-yawning.jpg");
  opacity: 0.5;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="profile-pic"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо! `opacity` не устраивал, т.к. внутри блока контент и он становился полупрозрачным. псевдоэлемент выручил!)